# Script for filtering and extracting Hive table names

Tags: bash, shell, hive, hiveql

I am trying to write a script that goes over all the databases in a hive server, and for each database returns the list of tables who contain a column with a certain name. Concretely (in pseudo-code):

```
list l
for d in show databases:
   use d
   for tbl in show tables:
     res = describe tbl | grep col_name
     if res not empty:
       l.append(tbl.name)
return l
```

I am not sure about how to code this. Any help? If there are some good references for combining these shell commands with pipes etc. I'd appreciate the recommendation.

Comment: Are you _indeed_ sure you want to do SQL queries in BASH? [Perl](https://dbi.perl.org/), anyone?

Comment: Not sure at all. New to this. Whatever will meet these needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `hive -e '<hive command>'` (regardless of your choice of scripting language):

`hive -e 'show databases'` will return all databases

`hive -e 'use $d; show tables'` will return all tables in database `$d`

`hive -e 'use $d; describe $tbl'` will describe table `$tbl` in database `$d`

Comment: The hive -e is what I was missing. The rest is just scripting. Thanks!!

Comment: @user181218 Note that each invocation is in a new context - use database must precede any command that is database specific.